# Different Plot's output defining a function

Tags: plotting, output, assignment

I want a plot with this function

```
-((H^3 T)/(200 Pi)) + (H^2 T^2)/96 + H^4 l + H^2 m
```

with

```
rule = {l -> 27/(40000 Pi^2), m -> -85, T -> 106}
```

So if I give as input

```
f = -((H^3 T)/(200 Pi)) + (H^2 T^2)/96 + H^4 l + 
  H^2 m   /. {l -> 27/(40000 Pi^2), m -> -85, T -> 106}
```

and plot

```
Plot[Log[Abs[f]] Sign[f], {H, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

the plot line is not continuous.

Instead, if I didn't set `f` and I explicitly write

```
Plot[Log[Abs[-((H^3 T)/(200 Pi)) + (H^2 T^2)/96 + H^4 l + 
  H^2 m   /. {l -> 27/(40000 Pi^2), m -> -85, T -> 106}
    ]] Sign[-((H^3 T)/(200 Pi)) + (H^2 T^2)/96 + H^4 l + 
  H^2 m   /. {l -> 27/(40000 Pi^2), m -> -85, T -> 106}
   ], {H, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

the plot line is continuous.

Why there is this difference?
Is there a way to obtain a continuous line labelling the function as f?

Comment: `Plot[Log[Abs[f]] Sign[f], {H, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: I do think it's still relevant to know *why* the difference in exclusions.

Comment: @Feyre Indeed it's intriguing, but I'm kinda stumped. With `f` as in the OP (so with `/.rule` already) consider this: `Plot[Log[Abs[f]] Sign[f] /. rule, {H, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> All]` (so I basically used the same `rule` twice!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why the difference arises

The difference arises because `Log[f]` (as well as `Sign[f]`) is discontinuous where `f == 0`, which `Plot` computes symbolically and gets different results in the two `Plot` codes. There should be vertical asymptotes at those points.  (So `Exclusions -> None` is not a fix, as it gives a continuous graph.)

Here are the exclusions computed by `Plot` in each of the OP's cases:

```
Visualization`ExpandExclusions[Log[f] Sign[f], {H}, Automatic]
(*
  {{Im[(769 H^2)/24 + (27 H^4)/(40000 π^2) - (53 H^3)/(100 π)] == 0, 
    Re[(769 H^2)/24 + (27 H^4)/(40000 π^2) - (53 H^3)/(100 π)] <= 0},
   {(769 H^2)/24 + (27 H^4)/(40000 π^2) - (53 H^3)/(100 π) == 0, True},
   {(769 H^2)/24 + (27 H^4)/(40000 π^2) - (53 H^3)/(100 π) == 0, True}}
*)

Visualization`ExpandExclusions[
 Log[Abs[-((H^3 T)/(200 Pi)) + (H^2 T^2)/96 + H^4 l + H^2 m /.
     {l -> 27/(40000 Pi^2), m -> -85, T -> 106}]] *
  Sign[-((H^3 T)/(200 Pi)) + (H^2 T^2)/96 + H^4 l + H^2 m /.
     {l -> 27/(40000 Pi^2), m -> -85, T -> 106}],
 {H}, Automatic]
(*
  {}
*)
```

One can see these calls with

```
Trace[
 (* plot command *),
 _Visualization`ExpandExclusions,
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

*Update:*
The reason no exclusions are produced is that the unevaluated expression being plotted contains the member `ReplaceAll` of the following blacklist, which prevents further analysis of potential exclusions:

```
Visualization`DiscontinuityDump`$BlackList
(*
  {CompiledFunction, InterpolatingFunction, LinearSolveFunction, 
   NearestFunction, TransformationFunction, NIntegrate, NSum, NDSolve, 
   FindRoot, FindMinimum, FindMaximum, NMinimize, NMaximize, FixedPoint, 
   FixedPointList, Nest, NestList, Fold, FoldList, NestWhile, 
   NestWhileList, Apply, Map, Table, Do, For, While, Set, SetDelayed, 
   Decrement, PreDecrement, Increment, PreIncrement, Rule, RuleDelayed, 
   ReplaceAll, ReplaceRepeated, Replace, Nearest}
*)
```

### Getting an accurate plot

The order of growth of `f` at the asymptotes is very small, and to get large enough values of `f` that look like asymptotes, it takes values of `H` that are closer to the singularities than `MachinePrecision` will allow.

For instance, to get a magnitude greater than `40`, we have to be within roughly `10^-24` of the singularities:

```
Block[ (* H near singularities *)
 {H = H + {-1*^-24, 1*^-24} /. 
    NSolve[f == 0 && 0 < H < 4000, H, WorkingPrecision -> 32]},
 Log[Abs[f]] Sign[f]
 ]
(*  {{-46.5568, 46.5568}, {41.780, -41.780}}  *)
```

It is impractical to do this with `Plot`, since it automatically controls selection of the sample points.  I will use [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) instead. If we include the points above, as well as one close to `H == 0` where there is another asymptote, we can get this picture:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{H, Log[Abs[f]] Sign[f]},
   {H, Union[Range[1.`32*^-20, 4000, 5], 
        Flatten[H + {-1*^-20, 1*^-20} /. 
         NSolve[f == 0 && 0 < H < 4000, H, WorkingPrecision -> 32]]]}], 
 PlotRange -> {-25, 25}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's virtually impossible to mark up the asymptotes because the graph is so close to them.  (One can try dashing or transparency, but the result is not very good, imo.)

Comment: Excellent answer (+1).  Does documentation exist for 21 forms of `Visualization`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks! No, not that I know of, and most seem not to have a definition.  They may be internal option names or constants set at runtime. In the case of `LegendReap`, I would guess it might be used to set up code in which it is changed to `Reap` at the appropriate execution time with `Block[]`. I've used `ExpandExclusions` on this site before. The `FindDate*` symbols seem to be the only other functions, and they might be useful if you're plotting dates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It's still not clear to me _why_ `Plot` gets different results in the two Plot codes. You said that is because `Plot` computes computes symbolically the Log. But it seems to me that `Plot` should compute in the same way both expressions; so why the different output?

Comment: @Giancarlo `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`, which means, at least in this case, that it symbolically analyzes the expression in the form you pass to `Plot`. The first form gets analyzed and the graph is separated at the discontinuities. Because of the `/.` (= `ReplaceAll`) in the second form, `Plot` ***automatically*** does not analyze the discontinuities (because of the blacklist). As a result, it connects the pieces.